# String is not formatted accordingly after I load it from a text file

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have new line characters in my CString ("\r\n") which I than save to a text file. I than reload the string from text file along with the control characters but when I display it, the control characters are also displayed as it is rather than creating new line.

```
// after I read the string from file
my_string = "This is firstline\r\nThis is second line";

AfxMessageBox(my_string);
```

The output of this is all text in one line while I am expecting two lines.

The debugger does show the my_string as I have indicated above so the string object clearly contains the control character but why is the strong not formatted accordingly?

Comment: It should show multiple lines. Can you post the full code ?

Comment: I am not saving the string through application, its a language file and where I save the strings in notepad. My application simply reads the string and I was expecting saving \r\n will create a new line but it doesn't, any hint how I store new line in the string in text file if this is not the right way?

Comment: @zadane You mean you actually save the four characters `backslash`, `lowercase-r`, `backslash`, `lowercase-n` in Notepad?

Comment: @Angew Yes, is there any other way I should be saving this symbols?

Comment: I should add that I am also storing %d and %s in other strings in the notepad text file and those works fine when I fill these values at run time. The problem I am facing is with `\r\n` characters.

Comment: I'm confused, because your comments down here are completely in opposition to what you say in your question. But if you type the characters `"\r\n"` and save that in notepad, that is four characters with no new line, and it will load as four characters with no new line.  Escape sequences are for your source code.  If you type `"\r\n"` in source code, the compiler replaces that with two characters which make up a new line.  If you want to store a new line in a file from notepad, you hit the enter key.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I think you just answered my question, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The escape sequences using the backslash are parsed and translated to the appropriate character code at compile time not runtime. In order for this to work you will need to process the string and replace the escape sequences yourself after you have loaded it from the file. The example below shows a simple way to do this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void replace_needle(
    std::string &haystack,
    const std::string& needle,
    const std::string& with)
{
    std::string::size_type pos;
    while((pos = haystack.find(needle)) != std::string::npos)
    {
        haystack.replace(pos, needle.size(), with);
    }

}
int main()
{
    // use double backslashes to simulate the exact string read from the file
    std::string str = "This is first line\\r\\nThis is second line";
    static const std::string needle1 = "\\n";
    static const std::string needle2 = "\\r";

    std::cout << "Before\n" << str << std::endl;

    replace_needle(str, needle1, "\n");
    replace_needle(str, needle2, "\r");

    std::cout << "After\n" << str << std::endl;
}
```

Below is a strictly MFC solution that does the same thing.

```
int main()
{
    // use double backslashes to simulate the exact string read from the file
    CStringA str = "This is first line\\r\\nThis is second line";

    std::cout << "Before\n" << str << std::endl;

    str.Replace("\\n", "\n");
    str.Replace("\\r", "\r");

    std::cout << "After\n" << str << std::endl;
}
```

You can of course replace the entire "\r\n" sequence rather than each individual escape value. I chose not to as I'm not sure of the amount of flexibility you are looking for. Both solutions produce the following output.

> Before
>   This is first line\r\nThis is second line
>   After
>   This is first line
>   This is second line